# how to "get" an upper layer from an existing (layerDrawable) background of an imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-imagebutton, layerdrawable

I am creating an android app for playing Chess.

I have used `layerDrawable` to display 2 layers of background (one layer to display a square of the Chessboard and another for the piece on it).

But the problem is when I want to move the piece from the existing square, I only need the upper layer (the piece) to move.

Is there any way that I can "get" the upper layer.

I tried `getBackground()` method, but it only returns a drawable, not a layerDrawable.

Comment: Your approach looks totally faulty, to me

Comment: Could you please suggest a better approach, I'm new at this.

Comment: Use a GridView with alternating background colors. And the piece is transparent (no need to redraw the background). That's all.